# Write value to dynamic array VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dynamic

Code worked fine with fixed dim array but when I have added line to Redim to make Results array dynamic the code will not allow results to be added to array coming up with "Type Mismatch" error. I am sure a simple fix, have played around but can I see it..

GP (Gross Profit) Range of values picked up form single column range GPRange and Price Change its from single row PriceRange).

```
Option Explicit
Sub CalcVolTable()
'Macro to produce table that shows relationship between price and volume  change
Dim PriceChangeAr As Variant, GPAr As Variant
Dim GPList, GPNum, PriceIndex, PriceChNum As Integer
Dim GP As Double


With ThisWorkbook

' Read all PriceChanges into a 1-dimensional array
    PriceChangeAr = (.Worksheets("Results").Range("PriceRange").Value2)

' Read all GP range into a 1-dimensional array
        GPAr =     Application.Transpose(.Worksheets("Results").Range("GPRange").Value)

'Clear Previous Results
    Range("VolTable").ClearContents
    Range("Output").Select

    'Set up Results Array
    'Dim VolResultsAr(1 To 8, 1 To 7) As Variant - this worked before I tried to make array dynamic
    Dim VolResultsAr As Variant
    PriceChNum = UBound(PriceChangeAr, 2)
    GPNum = UBound(GPAr)
    ReDim VolResults(1 To GPNum, 1 To PriceChNum) As Variant

    For GPList = LBound(GPAr) To UBound(GPAr)

        GP = GPAr(GPList)

        'Set Cost per Unit value to get right GP in calc
        Range("CostPerUnit").Value = 100 * (1 - GP)
            ' Now loop through each pricechange
            For PriceIndex = LBound(PriceChangeAr, 2) To UBound(PriceChangeAr, 2)

                'Reset Price and Vol adjt cell to zero
                Range("ChPrice") = 0
                Range("Chvol") = 0

            'enter new Price Cahnge value
                Range("ChPrice").Value = PriceChangeAr(1, PriceIndex)

                'Use goal seek to calc vol chage req'd to bring GP back to same preset value
                Range("GP").GoalSeek Goal:=GP, ChangingCell:=Range("ChVol")

                'Writes result to cells in table in spreadsheet
                Range("Output").Offset(GPList - 1, PriceIndex - 1).Value = Range("ChVol").Value

                'CODE FALLING DOWN HERE - TRYING TO WRITE EACH RESULT INTO ARRAY
                VolResultsAr(GPList, PriceIndex) = Range("ChVol").Value


            Next PriceIndex

        Next GPList

    Range("Output2").Resize(UBound(VolResultsAr, 1), UBound(VolResultsAr, 2)) = VolResultsAr

    Range("Output").Select


End With

MsgBox "done!"

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you gave the range addresses for all those named ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the arrays need to match you need to `ReDim VolResultsAr`

```
ReDim VolResults(1 To GPNum, 1 To PriceChNum) As Variant
ReDim VolResultsAr(1 To GPNum, 1 To PriceChNum) As Variant
```

---

And for lines like:

```
Dim GPList, GPNum, PriceIndex, PriceChNum As Integer .
```

Only `PriceChNum` is `Integer`, the others are variant. Is that what you intended? And `Integer` should be replaced with `Long` to avoid potential overflow

Comment: Redimming the same array was the issue. Note to self - keep variable names minimal and simple, and check consistent naming throughout!! The GPList, GPNum etc are integers as they are holding the size of the array - have Dimmed as Long rather than Variant. All good now. Thanks for help.